# how to set up an SCM in Xcode 4.x?

Tags: version-control, xcode4

hi friends i am facing problems to configure SCM with Xcode 4.x
And can u tell me how to upload my project to remote server from xcode repositories,and i want share the same project from server by using SCM

Answer (score 1):

Xcode acts only as an SCM *client* for Git and Subversion SCMS. It can create *local* Git repositories when you create your project, but not Subversion. Xcode does not help you create remote repositories specifically, it only lets you connect to them.

Which SCM system are you using? Git or Subversion (SVN)? Determine which one and follow *its* instructions for creating shared repositories on remote servers. They're both very different and Xcode can't help you there.

Once you have them set up, you can then let Xcode know about them either by:

1 - Using the command-line tools (git or svn) or your favorite GUI client to check out / clone your remote repository to some working copy / local clone. Then just open the project with Xcode and Xcode should auto-discover the settings.

or

2 - Opening the Repositories Organizer (Cmd-Shift-2, click Repositories tab) and adding the remote repository there.

Finally, if you have an *existing* Xcode project that is not under version control, you'll need to use the SCM-specific command line or your favorite GUI tool to bring the project under version control and get it into your remote repository in the way required by the SCM system you're using, then follow the above to let Xcode know about it.

Comment: i got it,successfully configured